# How to write a dialog confirmation box using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I would like to ask on how to create a dialog confirmation box for deleting a record using jQuery. I tried to search in Google but I don't understand it well since I'm a newbie in this field. In addition, I already implemented a Javascript alert but the technical requirement is to use a jQuery dialog instead of a native Javascript alert. Please help. Thanks in advance. Any reference link that has step by step guide will also be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Below is my current code that needs to be updated.

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
  var pKey = $(this).parent().siblings()[0].innerText;
  //Get the Id of the record to delete
  var record_id = $(this).attr("id");
  //Get the GridView Row reference
  var tr_id = $(this).parents("#.record");
  // Ask user's confirmation before delete records
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '../SampleOnly.asmx/Delete',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      //Pass the selected record id
      data: "{ 'Id':'" + pKey + "'}",
      success: function (data) {
        // Change the back color of the Row before deleting
        tr_id.css("background-color", "blue");
        Do some animation effect
        tr_id.fadeOut(500, function () {
          //Remove GridView row
          tr_id.remove();
          alert(' The record has been deleted successfully');
        });
      },
```

Comment: jQuery has some plugins for this, do you know which one you want to use?

Comment: you can use jQuery fancybox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jquery UI dialog to show confirm box

```
$('<div id="dvConfirmModal"></div>').appendTo('body')
.html('<div><h2>Are you sure you want to delete this record?</h2></div>')
.dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: 'Delete record',
    zIndex: 10000,
    autoOpen: true,
    width: 'auto',
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            //Your ajax code goes here
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Use this code with your $('.delete') button click event. before using this code you have to add a reference of Jquery UI. can be downloaded from http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm so glad that I got it correctly. Maybe someone like me may use this as reference in the future. See code below. Thanks!.

```
  $('.delete').click(function () {
 var pKey = $(this).parent().siblings()[0].innerText; 
 var record_id = $(this).attr("id");               
 var tr_id = $(this).parents(".record");     

$('<div id="dvConfirmModal"></div>').appendTo('body')
.html('<p>These item will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Please confirm by clicking the OK button.</p>')
.dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: 'Delete selected item?',
    zIndex: 500,
    autoOpen: true,
    width: 'auto',
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    buttons: {            
      Ok: function() {
                    $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                            url: '../SampleOnly.asmx/Delete',       
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: "{ 'Id':'" + pKey + "'}",        

                               success: function (data) {
                                tr_id.css("background-color", "red");
                                tr_id.fadeOut(500, function (){
                                tr_id.remove();
                                alert(' The record has been deleted successfully');
                                                            });
                                error: function (err) {
                                alert('Error encountered while processing your request. Try again later.');
                                                      }   
                                }                                 
                                });                                        
                $(this).dialog("close");
                      },  
      Cancel: function() {
                 $(this).dialog("close");
                         }
                      },
      close: function(event, ui) {
               $(this).remove();
                                 } 
    });
});
```